# Unique decomposition of $c$ sums of products of $k$ numbers greater than 1, allowing duplicates?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, prime-numbers

This question differs from [Unique decomposition of $c$ sums of products of $k$ prime numbers, allowing duplicates?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387441/unique-decomposition-of-c-sums-of-products-of-k-prime-numbers-allowing-dupl) in that prime number restriction is changed to any number greater than 1.

Suppose that there are $n$ different numbers greater than 1. Define procedure a) as following ($k \leq n$ and $k$ fixed): procedure a) for each time, we select one number out of $n$ possible cases and multiply it to the product (number may be repeated). For the first time, we choose a number and that is the product. We do this $k$ times.

Then, we do the following for $c$ times where $c$ is fixed: procedure b) we define variable $z$. For the first time procedure b) is started, $z = 0$. Now call procedure a) and get a result into variable $y$. Then we add $y$ to $z$ - and the sum replaces the original value of $z$ into $z$. We repeat this $c$ times.

So, step is: we call procedure b) (which then recursively calls procedure a) ) and see the result $z$.

Now the question is, is this $z$ unique in its decomposition, given $k$ and $c$? (So, there would be $c$ sums of product of $k$ numbers greater than 1, allowing duplicates.)

Or if not, what would be the general rule when this holds?

For every step, the set of $n$ numbers greater than 1 remains the same - that is, it does not change.